# Insert new data BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table in BigQuery:

```
+------------+---------+------+
|    date    | country | sum  |
+------------+---------+------+
| 2020-01-01 |  UK     | 10   |
| 2020-01-01 |  Spain  | 34   |
| 2020-01-01 | Germany | 78   |
| 2020-01-01 |  France | 81   |
+------------+---------+------+
```

With the UI of BigQuery, I edited the schema and created a new metric: AVG. I would like to insert this new info in this table from another table like this:

```
INSERT dataset.table_old (AVG) 
SELECT AVG(m) FROM table_m
```

If I do that I get it this:

```
+------------+---------+------+------+
|    date    | country | sum  |  AVG |
+------------+---------+------+------+
| 2020-01-01 |  UK     | 10   | NULL |
| 2020-01-01 |  Spain  | 34   | NULL |
| 2020-01-01 | Germany | 78   | NULL |
| 2020-01-01 |  France | 81   | NULL |
|    NULL    |  NULL   | NULL | 28   |
|    NULL    |  NULL   | NULL | 7    |
|    NULL    |  NULL   | NULL | 10   |
|    NULL    |  NULL   | NULL | 41   |
+------------+---------+------+------+
```

How could I get the correct table with the correspondent match?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want an _update_ here.  Please include data from the other table containing the averages.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem in that you need to apply `UPDATE` command rather than `INSERT` command. If you apply INSERT then it will treat it as a new Records.

Expected Solution:-
**Step 1**: You need to Identify over which field you are getting `AVG(m)` from table table_m, that can be joined with table table_old. It Could be (date, country or sum) based on your business requirement.
**Step 2**: Once you Joining Field in above step, then you can write following UPDATE query:-

```
UPDATE dataset.table_old a
SET AVG = (SELECT AVG(m) FROM table_m b where a.JOINING_Coll=b.JOINING_Coll GROUP BY Field) 
WHERE 1=1
```

Important part is `a.JOINING_Coll=b.JOINING_Coll` where you need to identify which filed will be used to join 2 tables and perform UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BQ `MERGE` statement.

1. add a new column `avg` in `table_od` with NULL value
2. Then do a MERGE operation below

Assuming you need to calculate the average value in table_m for each date and country

```
MERGE INTO table_old AS dest
USING(
  SELECT
    a.date,
    a.country,
    a.sum,
    b.avg
  FROM table_old AS a
  LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        AVG(m) as avg
      FROM table_m
      GROUP BY date, country
    ) AS b
    USING (date, country)
) AS source

ON  source.date = dest.date AND source.coutry = dest.country

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    date = dest.date, country = dest.country, sum = dest.sum, avg = dest.avg
```

For more information about [BQ MERGE statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement)